# What is the best method to access main data from child's components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application where validation requires referring to the app controller. My App controller looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  objectName: ObjectName;


  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.objectName= new ObjectName();
    this.objectName.objects1 = this.getObjects1();
    this.objectName.objects2 = this.getObjects2();
  }
```

What is the best method to access this data from child's components?

Comment: Move this to a service ?

Comment: Hi @user3302358, did an answer help you ? If so, can you please mark it as accepted ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is a direct child you can simply use an Input parameter. If it is a grandchild or a sibling then the best practice is to use a shared service and communicate vs a behaviorSubject.

[Read this, it is te official guide and will answer all your questions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Ok, I know this method but when you need to use data from app controller in child child child component only for validation I don't think it is best method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access any of the following inside the Parent Component, use `@ViewChild` decorator of Angular.

- Child Component
- Directive
- DOM Element

to retrieve value We need to do the following tasks:

- Import ViewChild and AfterViewInit from @angular/core
- Implement AfterViewInit life cycle hook to component class
- Create a variable with decorator @ViewChild
- Access that inside ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to do that with an `EventEmitter` as follow :

**emitter.helper.ts**

```
// Angular modules
import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

// Models
import { ObjectName }   from '...';

@Injectable()
export class EmitterHelper
{

  public static emitObjectName : EventEmitter<ObjectName> = new EventEmitter();

  public static sendObjectName(objectName : ObjectName) : void
  {
    this.emitObjectName.emit(objectName);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to share this helper by adding it to the `providers` of `app.module.ts`.

Now you can import and use the `EmitterHelper` between components :

**Component A**

```js
EmitterHelper.sendObjectName(this.objectName);
```

**Component B**

```js
EmitterHelper.emitObjectName.subscribe((objectName : ObjectName) =>
{
  console.log(objectName);
});
```